# Most important things to be proficient in before Calculus 1?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

What are the main things one should be proficient in before taking Calculus 1? Please be specific.

Comment: Trigonometry. Dear god trigonometry.

Comment: That's good to know because I know my trig like the back of my hand. I was looking for more specific things though. What kinds of things in trig are mostly seen?

Comment: Well various trig relations like double angle, half angle and the Pythagorean identity in all of its lovely forms. You should also be very comfortable with conic sections as these will come up time and time again in calculus.

Comment: Doing conics right now more in depth so nice to know!

Comment: Study. More specific: study a lot. Even more specific: study a godamn lot, and do lots of exercises. Having several Calculus books by your side (those things with paper and stuff, or else in an ipad or something like that) will surely help, too.

Comment: You might look at the old calculus books in your library. Many of them have a preliminaries section as a first chapter. Thomas calculus has one, and it backs up pretty much everything Cameron just said.

Comment: Okay sounds good. I already have the concepts of derivatives and integrals down but it's the computational aspect that I need to learn. Thanks guys!

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I've taught around 15 to 20 calculus 1 classes, and trigonometry never seemed to be much of a problem with students. Sure, some had difficulty in solving trig. equations (comes up in finding max/min of functions where trig. functions appear) and some in using the Law of Sines and the Law of Cosines in some applied max/min problems, but for me the most significant difference between the skills students had and the skills they needed was algebraic manipulation. On the other hand, trig. played a much higher role in calculus 2 (via integration techniques).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being comfortable and proficient with the fundamentals of algebra, functions, and graphs. These are more pervasive in Calculus I than even trigonometry (although that is important too).

More specifically, graphs of the standard functions (lines, power functions, abs value, exponentials, logs, basic rational functions, trig functions; translations and reflections; even, odd). Being comfortable manipulating abstract function expressions like $f(a+h)-f(a)$ and $f(g(x))$. Solving equations: linear, quadratic (factoring and quadratic formula), power functions (including fractional and/or negative powers), exponentials, logs.

After those, tack on the same skills for the 6 trig functions (certainly the big 3 at a minimum).

In my experience, weakness in these areas hinders the student moreso than doing the actual calculus.

PS Once those things are mastered, I'd encourage you---as much as possible---when you learn something new in calculus, always see if you can explain what you are learning in terms of a picture of some sort. Thinking geometrically will really help calculus to "make sense" and become more than pushing symbols around.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to manipulate polynomials:

- Add polynomials
- Multiply polynomials, FOIL technique and squaring a binomial especially
- Divide polynomials
- Partial Fractions of a polynomial quotient
- Binomial expansion
- Shifting up/down/left/right and scaling vertically and horizontally are helpful too
- Graphing polynomials (value at $\pm \infty$ and roots of small polynomials)

If you start calculus before you can do the above comfortably, you'll run into many roadblocks.  If you want pointers on any of the topics leave a comment and I'll expand on them.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise two things that took me a long time to realize. First, make sure algebra is very clear. Calculus is part of the study of functions and it is absolutely essential to be very clear about what a function is and what there is to be interested in about them before calculus. Second it is important to realize that the derivative of a function is a point property of the function, given by another function of the same variable, called the "derivative" of the original function, and has nothing to do with limits. Limits are useful for determining what a derivative is in a particular case but even that is academic since the properties of derivatives make it almost entirely unnecessary to differentiate using a limit. The properties of derivatives are especially nice and convenient. The antiderivative (integral) of a function is extremely curious. It is an interval property of a function and has the amazing property that for a given function, its value simply depends only on the location of the interval and not how the function behaves over the interval, contrary to what one might expect. (This gives rise to the so-called "definite" integral.) If you understand what calculus is about, it is very simple and ingenious.